# Take user input and onclick button it should load url according to input in new tab in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, axios, vite

I want to take city name as input and on button click it should call specific url https://www.google.com/maps/search/tourist+places+in+ **mumbai** with ending url with input value in react. It should open the url in new tab

Destination.jsx (file name)

```
import React from 'react'

const Destination = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
     <h1>Destination</h1> 
     <input type="text" name="place" class="form-control" id="place" placeholder="Enter place" />

     <button type="Submit" id="submit"> Search </button>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Destination
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this to search places in new tab.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Destination = () => {
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    window.open(
      `https://www.google.com/maps/search/tourist+places+in+${e.target.place.value}`,
      '_blank'
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Destination</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="place"
          class="form-control"
          id="place"
          placeholder="Enter place"
        />

        <button type="Submit" id="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Destination;
```

Comment: You should explain your answer as well. No offense, but It is certain the OP is new to ReactJs and needs to understand the concept here, rather than just copy-pasting the code.

Comment: @SalmanMalik Yes you are right but it is just 1 line of code that opens a new tab in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Create a state:

```
const [destination, setDestination] = useState("");
```

Then use this state to populate your search query like this:

```
<input type="text" name="place" class="form-control" id="place" placeholder="Enter place" value={destination} onChange={(e) => setDesitnation(e.target.value)} />
```

and then when you submit you can call a custom function on the `onClick()` of button:

```
<button id="submit" onClick={searchDestination}> Search </button>
```

The function might go somwthing like this:

```
const searchDestination = () => {
    window.location.href = `https://www.google.com/maps/search/tourist+places+in+${destination}`;
}
```